# Implementar menú en fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo una app en la cual estoy tratando de mostrar un menú en la pantalla. Pero, no se muestra el menú.

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.online) {
            String url ="http://main.xxxxxxxx.jp/Deluoode.html";
            try{
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.MAIN"));
                i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Fragment1:

```
    public class Catalogo extends Fragment {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;

        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        public Catalogo() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static Catalogo newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            Catalogo fragment = new Catalogo();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalogo, container, false);
        }

        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }



@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.menu.menu).setVisible(true);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


        /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Fragment2 es igual al primero solo que con otro nombre

Este es el código del menú:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/online"
        android:title="Base"
    />
</menu>
```

Según yo debería funcionar pero la verdad es que no he dado con la solución. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola, el menu que quieres mostrar es el lateral o el de arriba?

Comment: El de arriba que se situa en la esquina superior derecha @Carlosgub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que yo suelo hacer para no tener que cargar el menú en cada fragment de la aplicación es hacer un MenuFragment que implemente el menú y que contenga un FrameLayout que se encarga de inflar cada fragment.

Esto lo puedes hacer así:

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.MenuActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Después implementas el fragment que contiene el menú e infla el resto de fragments

**MenuFragment.java**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private static final String TAG = MenuFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu, container, false);

        setToolbar(view);
        setHomeFragment();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            //Aquí pones tantos 'case' como items tengas en el menú
            case R.id.actionContact:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ContactFragment())
                        .commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    //Este método inicializa el toolbar y le da opciones de menú
    public void setToolbar(View view){
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) this.getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    }

    //Este método infla el fragment que quieres que se cargue por defecto
    // dentro del FrameLayout
    private void setHomeFragment(){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva,

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, disculpa la demora. Pues, me sale esto dentro del método setToolbar: 
`setSupportActionBar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) in AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar)`

Comment: ¿En qué versión tienes las bibliotecas de compatibilidad? Yo uso AndroidX, creo que tu problema viene de ahí